# How to know if a window is maximized using pywin32?

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32

I need to check if a window is maximized using pywin32. I'm on a windows 10 machine.

I have looked through the documentation but can't find a straight solution, any leads?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`GetWindowPlacement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowplacement) API.

In pywin32, [`win32gui.GetWindowPlacement`](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32gui__GetWindowPlacement_meth.html) will return a tuple which can be tested as follows:

```
window = win32gui.FindWindow("Notepad", None)
if window:
    tup = win32gui.GetWindowPlacement(window)
    if tup[1] == win32con.SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED:
        print("maximized")
    elif tup[1] == win32con.SW_SHOWMINIMIZED:
        print("minimized")
    elif tup[1] == win32con.SW_SHOWNORMAL:
        print("normal")
```