# Using Python, how can I detect whether a program is minimized or maximized?

Tags: python, minimize

I am trying to detect if a window is open using win32gui.IsIconic(hWnd). What exactly do I put in to substitute hWnd?

My goal is pretty simple: If a program, for example Notepad, is maximized, I want a boolean to be true, and if not, it's false.

I am not 100% familiar with programming terms as I am a bit on the newer side of programming, so examples/specifics help tops.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to know if a window is maximized using pywin32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56387889/how-to-know-if-a-window-is-maximized-using-pywin32)

Answer (score 2):

This would probably work.

```py
window = win32gui.FindWindow("Notepad", None)
if window:
    tup = win32gui.GetWindowPlacement(window)
    if tup[1] == win32con.SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED:
        minimized = False
    elif tup[1] == win32con.SW_SHOWMINIMIZED:
        minimized = True
    elif tup[1] == win32con.SW_SHOWNORMAL:
        normal = True
```

The code is from this answer: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56387889/how-to-know-if-a-window-is-maximized-using-pywin32)